# How to use div as video source?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, webrtc, webvr

```
<video id="localVideo" src="#localVideo" crossOrigin="anonymous"
    autoplay="false"
    loop="true" style="display: none;"> </video>
```

This javascript is used to stream the video in the above div. I have used web rtc to get the video from the javascript below.

```
/*global socket, video, config*/
let peerConnection;

socket.on('offer', function(id, description) {
    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
    description=flipVideoCodec(description);
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(description)
    .then(() => peerConnection.createAnswer())
    .then(sdp => peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp))
    .then(function () {
        socket.emit('answer', id, peerConnection.localDescription);
    });
    peerConnection.onaddstream = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("localVideo").srcObject = event.stream;
    };
    peerConnection.onicecandidate = function(event) {
        if (event.candidate) {
            socket.emit('candidate', id, event.candidate);
        }
    };
});

socket.on('candidate', function(id, candidate) {
  peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
});

socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('watcher');
});

socket.on('broadcaster', function() {
  socket.emit('watcher');
});

socket.on('bye', function() {
    peerConnection.close();
});
```

Now i want to pass the retrived video in the div above to the javascript for webvr video source.

```
var gl = null;
      var panorama = null;
      var stats = null;
      function onContextLost( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log( 'WebGL Context Lost.' );
        gl = null;
        panorama = null;
        stats = null;
      }
      function onContextRestored( event ) {
        console.log( 'WebGL Context Restored.' );
        init(vrDisplay ? vrDisplay.capabilities.hasExternalDisplay : false);
      }
      var webglCanvas = document.getElementById("webgl-canvas");
      webglCanvas.addEventListener( 'webglcontextlost', onContextLost, false );
      webglCanvas.addEventListener( 'webglcontextrestored', onContextRestored, false );
      function getDefaultVideo() {
        const video = document.createElement( "video" );
        if(video.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="mp4v.20.8"')) {

          return ret;
        } else if (video.canPlayType('video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"')) {
          var src=localStream.getVideoTracks();
          return ret;
        } else {
          VRSamplesUtil.addError("No supported video available", 3000);
          return null;
        }
      }
      function init (preserveDrawingBuffer) {
        var glAttribs = {
          alpha: false,
          antialias: false,
          preserveDrawingBuffer: preserveDrawingBuffer
        };
        gl = webglCanvas.getContext("webgl", glAttribs);
        if (!gl) {
          gl = webglCanvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", glAttribs);
          if (!gl) {
            VRSamplesUtil.addError("Your browser does not support WebGL.");
            return;
          }
        }
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
        panorama = new VRPanorama(gl);
        var defaultVideo = getDefaultVideo();
        var videoUrl = WGLUUrl.getString(
            'videoUrl', defaultVideo);
        panorama.setVideo(videoUrl).catch(
            function(error) {
              if (error instanceof MediaError && error.code === 4) {
                panorama.setVideo(defaultVideo);
              }
            });
        var enablePerformanceMonitoring = WGLUUrl.getBool(
            'enablePerformanceMonitoring', false);
        stats = new WGLUStats(gl, enablePerformanceMonitoring);
        // Wait until we have a WebGL context to resize and start rendering.
        window.addEventListener("resize", onResize, false);
        onResize();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(onAnimationFrame);
      }
      // ================================
      // WebVR-specific code begins here.
      // ================================
      function onVRRequestPresent () {
        vrDisplay.requestPresent([{ source: webglCanvas }]).then(function () {
        }, function (err) {
          var errMsg = "requestPresent failed.";
          if (err && err.message) {
            errMsg += "<br/>" + err.message
          }
          VRSamplesUtil.addError(errMsg, 2000);
        });
      }
      function onVRExitPresent () {
        if (!vrDisplay.isPresenting)
          return;
        vrDisplay.exitPresent().then(function () {
        }, function () {
          VRSamplesUtil.addError("exitPresent failed.", 2000);
        });
      }
      function onVRPresentChange () {
        onResize();
        if (vrDisplay.isPresenting) {
          if (vrDisplay.capabilities.hasExternalDisplay) {
            VRSamplesUtil.removeButton(vrPresentButton);
            vrPresentButton = VRSamplesUtil.addButton("Exit VR", "E", "media/icons/cardboard64.png", onVRExitPresent);
          }
        } else {
          if (vrDisplay.capabilities.hasExternalDisplay) {
            VRSamplesUtil.removeButton(vrPresentButton);
            vrPresentButton = VRSamplesUtil.addButton("Enter VR", "E", "media/icons/cardboard64.png", onVRRequestPresent);
          }
        }
      }
      if (navigator.getVRDisplays) {
        frameData = new VRFrameData();
        navigator.getVRDisplays().then(function (displays) {
          if (displays.length > 0) {
            vrDisplay = displays[displays.length - 1];
            vrDisplay.depthNear = 0.1;
            vrDisplay.depthFar = 1024.0;
            init(true);
            if (vrDisplay.capabilities.canPresent)
              vrPresentButton = VRSamplesUtil.addButton("Enter VR", "E", "media/icons/cardboard64.png", onVRRequestPresent);
            // For the benefit of automated testing. Safe to ignore.
            if (vrDisplay.capabilities.canPresent && WGLUUrl.getBool('canvasClickPresents', false))
              webglCanvas.addEventListener("click", onVRRequestPresent, false);
            window.addEventListener('vrdisplaypresentchange', onVRPresentChange, false);
            window.addEventListener('vrdisplayactivate', onVRRequestPresent, false);
            window.addEventListener('vrdisplaydeactivate', onVRExitPresent, false);
          } else {
            init(false);
            VRSamplesUtil.addInfo("WebVR supported, but no VRDisplays found.", 3000);
          }
        }, function () {
          VRSamplesUtil.addError("Your browser does not support WebVR. See <a href='http://webvr.info'>webvr.info</a> for assistance.");
        });
      } else if (navigator.getVRDevices) {
        init(false);
        VRSamplesUtil.addError("Your browser supports WebVR but not the latest version. See <a href='http://webvr.info'>webvr.info</a> for more info.");
      } else {
        init(false);
        VRSamplesUtil.addError("Your browser does not support WebVR. See <a href='http://webvr.info'>webvr.info</a> for assistance.");
      }
      function onResize () {
        if (vrDisplay && vrDisplay.isPresenting) {
          var leftEye = vrDisplay.getEyeParameters("left");
          var rightEye = vrDisplay.getEyeParameters("right");
          webglCanvas.width = Math.max(leftEye.renderWidth, rightEye.renderWidth) * 2;
          webglCanvas.height = Math.max(leftEye.renderHeight, rightEye.renderHeight);
        } else {
          webglCanvas.width = webglCanvas.offsetWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
          webglCanvas.height = webglCanvas.offsetHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
        }
      }
      function getPoseMatrix (out, pose) {
        // When rendering a panorama ignore the pose position. You want the
        // users head to stay centered at all times. This would be terrible
        // advice for any other type of VR scene, by the way!
        var orientation = pose.orientation;
        if (!orientation) { orientation = [0, 0, 0, 1]; }
        mat4.fromQuat(out, orientation);
        mat4.invert(out, out);
      }
      function onAnimationFrame (t) {
        // do not attempt to render if there is no available WebGL context
        if (!gl || !stats || !panorama) {
          return;
        }
        stats.begin();
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        if (vrDisplay) {
          vrDisplay.requestAnimationFrame(onAnimationFrame);
          vrDisplay.getFrameData(frameData);
          // FYI: When rendering a panorama do NOT use view matricies directly!
          // That will make the viewer feel like their head is trapped in a tiny
          // ball, which is usually not the desired effect. Instead, render both
          // eyes from a single viewpoint.
          getPoseMatrix(viewMat, frameData.pose);
          if (vrDisplay.isPresenting) {
            gl.viewport(0, 0, webglCanvas.width * 0.5, webglCanvas.height);
            panorama.render(frameData.leftProjectionMatrix, viewMat);
            gl.viewport(webglCanvas.width * 0.5, 0, webglCanvas.width * 0.5, webglCanvas.height);
            panorama.render(frameData.rightProjectionMatrix, viewMat);
            vrDisplay.submitFrame();
          } else {
            gl.viewport(0, 0, webglCanvas.width, webglCanvas.height);
            mat4.perspective(projectionMat, Math.PI*0.4, webglCanvas.width / webglCanvas.height, 0.1, 1024.0);
            panorama.render(projectionMat, viewMat);
            stats.renderOrtho();
          }
        } else {
          window.requestAnimationFrame(onAnimationFrame);
          // No VRDisplay found.
          gl.viewport(0, 0, webglCanvas.width, webglCanvas.height);
          mat4.perspective(projectionMat, Math.PI*0.4, webglCanvas.width / webglCanvas.height, 0.1, 1024.0);
          mat4.identity(viewMat);
          panorama.render(projectionMat, viewMat);
          stats.renderOrtho();
        }
        stats.end();
      }
      })();
```

Also Can you please suggest me if there is another method to pass the video the the webvr using webrtc as video source?